# Scale up 4k display in a 3-monitor setup

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I just got a 4k display. I have it set up in the middle with the other 2 displays (1080p) on each side portrait mode.

Is it possible in Ubuntu to upscale only the 4k display? Similar to the "zoom" feature in windows and OS X.

I tried it using xrandr, and when I did .5x.5 everything got blurry, which isn't what I want. I basically want the 4k display to function like a high dpi 1440p display.

Really appreciate any help here!

I'm running 17.04 with a GTX 1080 with the proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to go to System settings >> display >> scale for menu and title bars

If you want a scale of the whole screen you have to use xrandr. To achieve optimal result you should use multiple of your resolution (e.g. map a pixel to four)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the menu bar scaling and that only helps with the menus :) What would be the exact command using xrandr to achieve what i'm looking for (to make a 4k display display at 1440p@2x pixel ratio?

Comment: Should be something similar to `xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode "2560x1440" --scale "0.5x0.5"`  assuming eDP-1 is your monitor name (you can check it by running `xrandr` and seeing which display is the primary one).

Comment: Unfortunately, those settings keep everything blurry still.

Comment: Whats your exact display resolution?