# Fixing scale for 4k and 1080p monitor

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, 4k-monitor

I find it difficult to believe that there isn't a GUI for changing the scaling for multiple monitors, but I am prepared to use `randr` if necessary.

I have a new 3840x2160 monitor which I've placed alongside my existing 1920x1080 monitor. If I leave scaling as is then the 1080p monitor looks fine but the 4k one is terribly small. Vice versa for setting scaling to 200%.

How can I fix the scaling to work for both monitors? I adapted this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929397/scale-up-4k-display-in-a-3-monitor-setup) with my own resolution but received the following:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode "3840x2160" --scale "0.5x0.5" --crtc 1
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

If I leave the `--crtc` argument out then `xrandr` just misidentifies the monitor, like so: `xrandr: Configure crtc 2 failed`.

What can I do to get the expected results? Mac just does what you would expect and automatically fix the scaling for both monitors.

Answer (score 1):

I have *partially* solved this by using Wayland, which enables me to change the scaling per monitor, as well as enabling fractional scaling.

This is great, but it results in an unusual problem. The upscaled monitor, understandably, has blurry text. This is the case for the taskbar, window bars, and all text in applications - **except** for the text in applications like Terminal, Settings, Ubuntu Software, or GNOME Tweaks, which look perfect on every monitor. Even the window bar for each of these applications looks fine, whereas the text on the window bar of all other applications is blurry.

Anyway, I hope this answer helps someone.