# Increasing resolution for external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xps

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on XPS 15 7590 and I got two 27" Samsung Monitors that are docked to my laptop. While my laptop easily gets a resolution of 3840x2160 (16:9), the 2 monitors only get 1920x1080(16:9).[image]

And due to this, everything in the monitors is incredibly zoomed in.

Is there a fix for this? I should get better resolution on 27" monitors than my 15" laptop.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by `docked to my laptop` exactly how is each monitor connected, what make/model of dock or hub and what output/input cables? When you connect a HDMI/DP monitor directly to a PC the monitor/PC communicate and the PC knows all the supported resolutions and refresh rates. If you are using a dock or a hub or USB-C output or something then I suspect Ubuntu cannot get that information. You may need to use `xrandr`, `cvt` to manually add/change the monitors resolution: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Answer (score 0):

If you enable fractional scaling you can set a different scaling for each monitor. You can also check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206896/fixing-scale-for-4k-and-1080p-monitor).